# is Key Sort, and thus a data structure to allocate keys to an object's members, a viable alternative to quicksort and merge sort and their variants

Tags: c++, sorting

Learning about sorting algorithms... In a specialized case where the values in a list are incremented from 1 to n --> and thus the values become keys to their position in the list

```
GenerateNumbers(std::vector<int>& values){
     for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
          values.push_back(i+1);
}
```

We then shuffle the list...

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::shuffle(std::begin(values), std::end(values), mt);
```

and sort, using the values as the index where they belong in the list...

```
void KeyIndexSort(std::vector<int> &values) {//Linear (0(n)) Time Complexity ---- constant (0(1)) Space Complexity

int indexStart = 0; //indexStart Begins at first element of List e.g [2][1][4][3] indexStart is at location [2]
int indexMid = (values.size() / 2); //indexMid Begins in middle of List e.g [2][1][4][3] indexMid is at location [4]

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    if (values[indexMid] != indexMid + 1)//if value found in List[indexMid] is not equal to (indexMid + 1) Swap values
        Swap(values, indexMid);//e.g List = [2][1][4][3] indexMid starts at [4] Swap with [3]
                               //result =  [2][1][3][4]
    else {
        ShiftIndexRight(indexMid, values.size());//else indexMid is equal --> shift indexMid to the Right one Position
                                                 //e.g List = [2][1][3][4] indexMix in Position [3] shift indexMid to position [4]                                              
    }

    if (values[indexStart] != indexStart + 1)//if value found in List[indexStart] is not equal to indexStart Swap values
        Swap(values, indexStart);//e.g List = [2][1][4][3] indexStart begins at [2] Swap with [1]
                                 //result = [1][2][4][3]
    else {
        ShiftIndexRight(indexStart, values.size());//else indexStart is equal --> shift indexStart to the right on Position
                                      //e.g List = [1][2][4][3] indexStart in Position [1] shift indexStart to position [2]
    }
}
```

Helper Functions

```
void ShiftIndexRight(int &index, const int size) {
if (index < size - 1)//if index value is less than size of List
    ++index;//increment index --> e.g [1][2][3][4] index = [1] move to position [2]
}

void Swap(std::vector<int>& values, const int index) {
    int temp = values[index];
    values[index] = values[temp - 1];
    values[temp - 1] = temp;
}
```

Being an 0(n) runtime it is faster than both quick sort and merge sort (and their variations)

**Example runtime using 2 million non duplicate values ranging from 1 - 2 million over 30 shuffled runs:**

***Dual Pivot QuickSort with binary insertion sort cutoff at 15 (Sedgewick - Princeton implementation - shuffled n(log(n)) time, 0(1) space):*** 2.65 seconds on average

***MergeSort with binary insertion sort cutoff at 15 (Sedgewick - Princeton implementation - n(log(n)) time, 0(n) space):*** 2.49 seconds on average

***KeyIndexSort 0(n) time, 0(1) space:*** 0.33 seconds on average

Since KeyIndexSort was so quick I decided to run the algorithm again with more values...

**10 million non duplicate values ranging from 1 - 10 million over 30 shuffled runs:**

***KeyIndexSort: 0(n) time, 0(1) space:*** 2.08 seconds on average

Still learning about time and space complexity calculations...

should we then consider a data structure **when space is not an issue** that holds an array of key values (index locations) for each member of the data structure... Note: on each insertion of a new object we would have to find the index for each member in that object (do a merge or quick sort for each member and change the indexes accordingly)

c = number of members in data structure... insertion of new object would take c * n(log(n)) time approximately... if my math is correct...

```
struct DataStructure{
    int index[2];//index location of members in struct

    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
};
```

we should then be able to sort the indexes of each member as opposed to the member itself... however if I am correct, this is 0(n)^2 space complexity for the data structure... that may be an issue...

as an aside, I have yet to find a data set, whether small or large, where Quick Sort outperforms Merge Sort, though they are close up to a point... However, again, with my implementation of Merge Sort it is 0(n) space complexity... thus, I rationalize the performance by noting that an increase in space complexity can decrease time complexity...

I have yet to study Tim Sort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the data along with an index of the current positions, you are effectively storing a sorted data structure.

As you mentioned, insertion (and also removal) of data into your proposed structure is really inefficient. You need to sort at every single insertion. Normally, sorting is an operation you only have to do once.

If you want a data struture that can be efficiently sorted all the time, consider using something like `std::map`, a red-black tree.

Alternatively, you can store the data in a sorted vector. Then insertion takes linear time per member which is still more efficient than your `O(n log n)` per insertion.

Comment: Most relational databases use both `std::vector` and `std::map`.  The `std::vector` is the table, unsorted.  The `std::map<key, vector_index>` is an index table used to access the data is a sorted method (reducing the need to resort the vector).

Comment: For small datasets, a linear search is often same speed or faster.  Sorting and using algorithms have overhead, which may slow down efficiency for small datasets.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- i'll take a look at this, running a brute force seaching algorithm on a small dataset vs running binary insertionSort + binary search... assuming very small dataset... dataset size 15 or so...

Comment: @Henk I have yet to come across many data structures in my studies... I knew there was a possibility of a built-in type or known data structure that would make me reconsider my approach... much appreciated!!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews searching in linear time (brute force) should always be faster than sorting and then searching... n < n(log(n)) + log(n) if this is what your saying... :)  took me a while...

Comment: with the proposed data structure - insertion and deletion of new object would take 0(n) time - in the worst case you would insert the new object at the beginning of the list - you would then have to go through the remaining list objects and increment or decrement their positions for each object member... char variables can be changed into key values 'a' - 'a' + 1 = 1... since a string is an array of type char, can we change strings into key values... at first glance I think a compression algorithm is necessary...

Comment: @jwilhelms: Simplified, I am saying that on small datasets, linear (brute force) searches are as fast, if not faster, than a binary search and other algorithmic searches.  Linear search has less overhead than the other searches.  Most of the time, the execution time difference is negligible.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews got ya, on a sorted list - 0(n) may be faster than 0(log(n)) due to overhead on small datasets… assuming a data set of 5 elements searching for the last element in the list - linear search would take 5 iterations while 0(log(n)) would take 3 - the overhead would have to be greater than 2 iterations for linear time to be faster… either way it would take like .00000001 seconds to find with either searching algorithm… you could also make the binary search inline to remove some overhead I believe…

Comment: It is not just the number of operations to consider, but also cache efficiency and branch prediction. This is the reason why linear search is so efficient for small data sets.

Comment: I see what you guys are saying, looked over Binary Search again, the amount of work it does per iteration, and read up on it more... "If the number of components in the list is small (say, fewer than 20 items), a sequential search algorithm is faster [Than Binary Search] because it performs less work at each iteration" --> Programming and Problem Solving 6th Edition C++.... Thanks much!!!